# Can someone help me figure out why this zip code class won't find a zip code in range?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a class from https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-ZipCode-Class to create a zip code locator. It works most of the time, however, there are some times, that one of the functions in the class do not seem to work. For example, if I do this:

```
<?php
//Include the class
require_once('zipcode.php');
$zipSearch=new ZipCode(51301);
$zipCode=$zipSearch->getZipCode();
echo round($zipSearch->getDistanceTo("56187"), 2);
?>
```

This returns 40.16 for the miles apart, however, if I run this:

```
<?php
//Include the class
require_once('zipcode.php');
$zipSearch=new ZipCode(51301);
$zipCode=$zipSearch->getZipCode();

foreach ($zipSearch->getZipsInRange(0, 100) as $miles => $zip) {
    $getMiles = round($miles, 1);
    $zipDistance["$zip"] = $getMiles;
}
?>
```

This zip code of 56187 never shows up. Even though this distance is only 40.16.

I assume it has to do the the select query that is being run with the calculations, but to be honest, I am not smart enough to understand exactly what is going on.

Here is the function that just gets the distance between 2 zip codes and it works:

```
<?php
private function calcDistanceSql($location)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT 3956 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN((RADIANS(t2.lat) - '
              .'RADIANS(t1.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(t1.lat)) * '
              .'COS(RADIANS(t2.lat)) * POW(SIN((RADIANS(t2.lon) - '
              .'RADIANS(t1.lon)) / 2), 2)), '
              .'SQRT(1 - POW(SIN((RADIANS(t2.lat) - RADIANS(t1.lat)) / 2), 2) + '
              .'COS(RADIANS(t1.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t2.lat)) * '
              .'POW(SIN((RADIANS(t2.lon) - RADIANS(t1.lon)) / 2), 2))) '
              .'AS "miles" '
              ."FROM {$this->mysql_table} t1 INNER JOIN {$this->mysql_table} t2 ";


        switch ($this->location_type) {

            case ZipCode::LOCATION_ZIP:
                // note: zip code is sanitized in the constructor
                $sql .= "WHERE t1.zip_code = '{$this->zip_code}' ";
                break;

            case ZipCode::LOCATION_CITY_STATE:
                $city = @mysql_real_escape_string($this->city);
                $state = @mysql_real_escape_string($this->state_prefix);
                $sql .= "WHERE (t1.city = '$city' AND t1.state_prefix = '$state') AND t2.zip_code = '$zip_to'";
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid location type for '.__CLASS__);
        }

        switch (ZipCode::locationType($location))
        {
            case ZipCode::LOCATION_ZIP:
                $zip_to = $this->sanitizeZip($location);
                $sql .= "AND t2.zip_code = '$zip_to'";
                break;
            case ZipCode::LOCATION_CITY_STATE:
                $a = $this->parseCityState($location);
                $city = @mysql_real_escape_string($a[0]);
                $state = @mysql_real_escape_string($a[1]);
                $sql .= "AND (t2.city = '$city' AND t2.state_prefix = '$state')";
                break;
        }

        $r = @mysql_query($sql);

        if (!$r) {
            throw new Exception(mysql_error());
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($r) == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Record does not exist calculating distance between $zip_from and $zip_to");
        }

        $miles = mysql_result($r, 0);
        mysql_free_result($r);

        return $miles;
    }
?>
```

Here is the function that is used to get all the zip codes in a distance range and is not returning the zip code I am looking for:

```
<?php
public function getZipsInRange($range_from, $range_to, $units=1)
    {
        if (empty($this->zip_code_id)) $this->setPropertiesFromDb();

        $sql = "SELECT 3956 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              .'RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * '
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2)), SQRT(1 - POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * "
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2))) AS \"miles\", z.* FROM {$this->mysql_table} z "
              ."WHERE zip_code <> '{$this->zip_code}' " 
              ."AND lat BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lat} - (25 / 69.172), 4) "
              ."AND ROUND({$this->lat} + (25 / 69.172), 4) "
              ."AND lon BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lon} - ABS(25 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
              ."AND ROUND({$this->lon} + ABS(25 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
              ."AND 3956 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * "
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2)), SQRT(1 - POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * "
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2))) <= $range_to "
              ."AND 3956 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * "
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2)), SQRT(1 - POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lat}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lat)) / 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * "
              ."COS(RADIANS({$this->lat})) * POW(SIN((RADIANS({$this->lon}) - "
              ."RADIANS(z.lon)) / 2), 2))) >= $range_from "
              ."ORDER BY 1 ASC";

        $r = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$r) {
            throw new Exception(mysql_error());
        }
        $a = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            // TODO: load ZipCode from array
            $a[$row['miles']] = new ZipCode($row);
        }

        return $a;
    }
?>
```

For the full class you can see it here: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-ZipCode-Class/blob/master/zipcode.php

Thank you!

Comment: Wow, if any query could benefit from using `BETWEEN` instead of `<=` and `>=`, that's it. It could also use `HAVING` instead of repeating the calculation in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I am willing to pay for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it, but I'm not sure how... I just played with number and anytime something was divided by 25 I changed it to 400. It now returns the results I want, however, I am not sure why...

CHANGES I MADE:

It was:

```
."AND lat BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lat} - (25 / 69.172), 4) "
."AND ROUND({$this->lat} + (25 / 69.172), 4) "
."AND lon BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lon} - ABS(25 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
."AND ROUND({$this->lon} + ABS(25 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
```

It changed it to:

```
."AND lat BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lat} - (400 / 69.172), 4) "
."AND ROUND({$this->lat} + (400 / 69.172), 4) "
."AND lon BETWEEN ROUND({$this->lon} - ABS(400 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
."AND ROUND({$this->lon} + ABS(400 / COS({$this->lat}) * 69.172)) "
```

If anyone can comment and explain what this change did, I would appreciate it.